# how to call compoment from another frame

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, frame, jcomponent

hi i have two frames created in the same way:

```
public class DateFilter extends JFrame {

private final JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
private final JDateChooser dateChooser_1 = new JDateChooser();
private final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
private final JButton filtruotiButton = new JButton();

public DateFilter() {
    super();
    setBounds(100, 100, 277, 167);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try {
        jbInit();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void jbInit() throws Exception {
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setTitle("Priemimo datos filtras");
    setResizable(false);

    getContentPane().add(dateChooser);
    dateChooser.setBounds(70, 40, 117, 20);

    getContentPane().add(dateChooser_1);
    dateChooser_1.setBounds(70, 65, 117, 20);
    dateChooser_1.setEnabled(false);
...
```

tell me plz someone how to get data from one to another frame
for example if i want to place date from this frame's dateChooser to another frame's textField using button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to pass the instance of the first frame to the second and than call a method on this instance.

Little sample code:

```
public class FrameA extends JFrame {

  public void setSomeDate() {
  }
}

public class FrameB extends JFrame {

  public void doSomething() {
    FrameA frameA = new FrameA();
    frameA.setSomeDate();
  }
}
```

Since I guessed that you are a beginner, I answered with this pretty simple and basic example. A more sophisticated way would be using the MVC pattern, of course!

Comment: ok thnx, its simple but a littel bit irracional,
can you post example with mvc

Comment: About the example: googling for "MVC java" gives a lot of good examples and tutorials.

Comment: *irrational sorry for mistake

Comment: @Edgar: There's an MVC related answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).